# Culture NumberFormat change and thousand/hundred separator positioning

Tags: crystal-reports, cultureinfo

I am using Crystal Report 13 with Visual Studio 2013. I want my numeric field type as 22,33,45,405.33 instead of 223,345,405.33.

My question is that if I add NumberGroupSizes(int[]{3,2,2,2,2,2,2}) of NumberFormatInfo and set it to current culture, and if I set the culture to reportviewer or something, it it possible to show number field value as my desire format?

Answer (score 0):

Use this formulla

ToText({numeric_field},"###,###,###.##")